# Statistics Question involving Mode : Given the set of data $1,1,2,2,2,3,3,x,y$ ....

Tags: statistics, proof-verification

I was studying for some quizzes when a wild question appears. It goes like this:

> Given the set of data $1,1,2,2,2,3,3,x,y$, where $x$ and $y$ represent two different integers. If the mode is $2$, which of the following is true?
>
> A. If $x = 1 \space or \space 2$, then $y = 3$
>
> B. If $x = 1 \space or \space 3$, then $y = 2$
>
> C. If $x = 1 \space or \space 2$, then $y = 2$
>
> D. If $x = 1 \space or \space 3$, then $y = 3$

**My work**

The mode is the most common number occuring in a sequence of numbers. In this case, it's $2$.

If I think about **A**, that would be false, because if I'm going to put $x = 1$ and $y = 3$, completing the sequence $1,1,2,2,2,3,3,1,3$.
The mode will be $2$ and $3$. The problem states that mode must be $2$. If I'm going to put $x = 2$ and $y = 3$, completing the sequence $1,1,2,2,2,3,3,2,3$,
the mode will be $2$, making **A** correct. In short, **A** is **half-truth**

If I think about **B**, that would be true, because if I'm going to put $x = 1$ and $y = 2$, completing the sequence $1,1,2,2,2,3,3,1,2$.
The mode will be $2$. The problem states that mode must be $2$. If I'm going to put $x = 3$ and $y = 2$, completing the sequence $1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,2$,
the mode will be $2$, making **B** correct. In short, **B** is **true**

If I think about **C**, that would be true, because if I'm going to put $x = 1$ and $y = 2$, completing the sequence $1,1,2,2,2,3,3,1,2$.
The mode will be $2$. The problem states that mode must be $2$. If I'm going to put $x = 2$ and $y = 2$, completing the sequence $1,1,2,2,2,3,3,2,2$,
the mode will be $2$, making **C** true. In short, **C** is **true**

If I think about **D**, that would be false, because if I'm going to put $x = 1$ and $y = 3$, completing the sequence $1,1,2,2,2,3,3,1,3$.
The mode will be $2$ and $3$. The problem states that mode must be $2$. If I'm going to put $x = 3$ and $y = 3$, completing the sequence $1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3$,
the mode will be $3$, making **D** false. In short, **D** is **false**

The problem is, I got two choices that says they were **TRUE**, which is the choices **B** and **C**.

I don't know what would be the correct one, akin to choosing two equally-potential suitors.

What might be the correct choice in this problem?

Comment: A and C cannot both be true as they contradict each other.

Comment: C and D run into issues with "$x$ and $y$ represent two different integers"

Comment: B looks like the only potential answer with no issues and it makes sense: if there are three $1$s or $3$s then for $2$ to be the unique mode there must be four $2$s

Comment: @Henry What might be the approach for this problem? Why B works?

Answer (score 1):

When you read something like:

> If $x=a$ or $b$, then $y=c$

What this means is that for the values of $x$, $y$ must equal $c$ in order to satisfy the condition that the sequence has a mode of 2. And if at least one value of $x$ does not satisfy the condition for $y$, then the entire thing is false.

For example, $A$ is not true. It's false - let's see why.

As you correctly stated, we have sequences $$\begin{cases}1,1,2,2,2,3,3,1,y \\ 1,1,2,2,2,3,3,2,y\end{cases}$$
Now, for sequence 1, $y$ cannot be $3$, as this results in a mode other than $2$.

However, for sequence $2$, $y$ does not have to be $3$ - if $y=1,2$ or $3$ the mode will always be $2$. Thus, $y$ does not necessarily equal $3$.

Now, when $x=2$ in this case, **we are not guaranteed** that $y=2$, hence $A$ is false.

---

Notice that for $B$, we have sequences $$\begin{cases} 1,1,2,2,2,3,3,1,y \\ 1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,y\end{cases}$$

For sequence 1 $y$ must be $2$, or else the mode of the sequence is not $2$.

For sequence 2, $y$ must be $2$ as well, or else the mode of the sequence does not equal $2$.

Thus, due to the property that the sequence has a mode of $2$, when $x$ equals $1$ or $3$ **we are guaranteed** that $y$ must equal $2$.

Hence $B$ is correct.